# Merge 2 Javascript Files into one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two JS files that perform the same function with the only differences being the **.click trigger** and the **AJAX URL** that is called. **I am trying to merge the scripts into one.** I am sure it is possible but being a bit of a JS novice am finding it a little tricky.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

// LOAD GAME JSON DATA  VIA AJAX
$('.gameCta').click(function(){

    id = $(this).children('span.title').attr('data-id');


        // LOAD GAME PROVIDERS
        $("#game_provs").load("http://localhost:8888/projects/superfreerespo/" + id + "/ .gameBox-Ops");

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8888/projects/superfreerespo/" + id + "?json=get_category_posts&slug=games",
        method: "GET",
        data: {json:  1},
        dataType: "JSON"}).done(function( data ) {



        // LOAD GAME INFORMATION
        $("#game-name").html(data.post.title);
        $("#game-reels").html(data.post.custom_fields.reels);
        $("#game-paylines").html(data.post.custom_fields.paylines);
        $("#game-minBet").html(data.post.custom_fields.min_bet);
        $("#game-maxBet").html(data.post.custom_fields.max_bet);
        $("#game-jackpot").html(data.post.custom_fields.jackpot);
        $("#game-info").html(data.post.custom_fields.game_info);

        $('#next').attr('data-id', data.next_url);
        $('#previous').attr('data-id', data.previous_url);



        // LOAD GAME THUMBNALS
        var gameThumbSrc = new String(data.post.custom_fields.game_name);
        gameThumbSrc = gameThumbSrc.replace(/ /g,'');


        $('#gameBoxGallery').html('');
            for(i = 0;  i<= 2; i++){
                image = '<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/games/screenshots/' + gameThumbSrc + '-' + i + '.jpg" class="gameThumb">'
            $('#gameBoxGallery').append(image);
        };

        // ZOOM FIRST THUMBNAIL
        $('#gameBox-Screenshot').html('');
            image = '<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/games/screenshots/' + gameThumbSrc + '-0' + '.jpg" id="gameScreenshot">'
            $('#gameBox-Screenshot').append(image);
        })
    })
});

</script>


<script>
$(document).on('click', '.direction', function(){ 

    move = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $.ajax({
        url: move,
        method: "GET",
        data: {json:  1},
        dataType: "JSON"}).done(function( data ) {

        // LOAD GAME INFORMATION
         $("#game-header").html(data.post.title);
        $("#game-name").html(data.post.title);
        $("#game-reels").html(data.post.custom_fields.reels);
        $("#game-paylines").html(data.post.custom_fields.paylines);
        $("#game-minBet").html(data.post.custom_fields.min_bet);
        $("#game-maxBet").html(data.post.custom_fields.max_bet);
        $("#game-jackpot").html(data.post.custom_fields.jackpot);
        $("#game-info").html(data.post.custom_fields.game_info);

    $('#next').attr('data-id', data.next_url);
    $('#previous').attr('data-id', data.previous_url);

        // LOAD GAME THUMBNALS
        var gameThumbSrc = data.post.custom_fields.game_name;
        $('#gameBoxGallery').html('');
            for(i = 0;  i<= 2; i++){
                image = '<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/games/' + gameThumbSrc + '/screenshots/' + gameThumbSrc + '-thumb-' + i + '.png" class="gameThumb">'
            $('#gameBoxGallery').append(image);
        };


        var gameThumbSrc = data.post.custom_fields.game_name;
        $('#gameBox-Screenshot').html('');
            image = '<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/games/' + gameThumbSrc + '/screenshots/' + gameThumbSrc + '-large-0' + '.png" id="gameScreenshot">'
            $('#gameBox-Screenshot').append(image);


        })
    });

        // ZOOM THUMBNAIL ONCLICK
        $(document).on('click', '.gameThumb', function(){ 
            $('#gameScreenshot').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go through your two files, find lines where they differ and extract similarly named variables until you have two identical code blocks.
2. Once the blocks are identical extract a function with the variables you just extracted as arguments.
3. Replace these blocks with calls to your new function passing your parametric variables in as arguments.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function load (url) {
        // ajax and stuff...
    }

    $('.gameCta').click(function(){
        var url = // functionality to get the url...

        // other functionality...

        load(url);
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.direction', function() { 
        var url = $(this).attr('data-id');

        // other functionality...

        load(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the route I want to take but I am a little lost reproducing it, could you expand your answer please?

Answer (score 0):

you can take out the ajax call and make a function like this

```
function call_ajax(url, request_data) {
  $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        data: request_data,
        dataType: "JSON"}).done(function( data ) {



        // LOAD GAME INFORMATION
        $("#game-name").html(data.post.title);
        $("#game-reels").html(data.post.custom_fields.reels);
        $("#game-paylines").html(data.post.custom_fields.paylines);
        $("#game-minBet").html(data.post.custom_fields.min_bet);
        $("#game-maxBet").html(data.post.custom_fields.max_bet);
        $("#game-jackpot").html(data.post.custom_fields.jackpot);
        $("#game-info").html(data.post.custom_fields.game_info);

        $('#next').attr('data-id', data.next_url);
        $('#previous').attr('data-id', data.previous_url);



        // LOAD GAME THUMBNALS
        var gameThumbSrc = new String(data.post.custom_fields.game_name);
        gameThumbSrc = gameThumbSrc.replace(/ /g,'');


        $('#gameBoxGallery').html('');
            for(i = 0;  i<= 2; i++){
                image = '<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/games/screenshots/' + gameThumbSrc + '-' + i + '.jpg" class="gameThumb">'
            $('#gameBoxGallery').append(image);
        };

        // ZOOM FIRST THUMBNAIL
        $('#gameBox-Screenshot').html('');
            image = '<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/games/screenshots/' + gameThumbSrc + '-0' + '.jpg" id="gameScreenshot">'
            $('#gameBox-Screenshot').append(image);
        })
    });
}
```

Now you call this ajax function on both events. With out having much duplicate code

Like this you can call

```
$('.gameCta').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).children('span.title').attr('data-id');
  var url = "http://localhost:8888/projects/superfreerespo/" + id + "/ .gameBox-Ops";
  var data =  {json:  1};
  call_ajax(url, data);
});
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how I would call this function?